# Windows App certification kit process is getting stuck while testing .exe

Tags: windows, uwp, visual-studio-2017, win-universal-app, app-certification-kit

Windows app certification kit process is getting stuck while testing .exe file. After clicking cancel also process does not get killed. 
After I killed the process from task manager, next time the kit does not get launched. After restarting system, it works. 
Is there any process that needs to be killed to restart the kit without restarting system? 
Also how to check if the kit is progressing the .exe testing?

Comment: A lot of issues like this are caused by other programs holding handles open for files. In particular, antivirus scanners. If you have something like that running it's worth setting some cofig for it ignore your build folders. Hopefully that helps resolve things.

Comment: In this case, the Windows app certification kit is getting stuck while testing .exe and when the process is killed from task manager, next time it can be launched only after restarting the system. It seems some intermediate process is still running. Primarily I need to know why it is not able to process .exe file and how to recover the process if it gets stuck without restarting the system.

Comment: If you have a way to reproduce the issue, I'm happy to take a look and see if there are other clues. Feel free to mail me at dotnetnative@microsoft.com. Alternately, if you don't think it's likely you'll ever fail WACK etc, you can disable those checks in newer VS 2019 (16.2.2) using a checkbox during packaging that is something like "add artifacts for validation with store certification toolkit".